# Exporting Release Build FlashBuilder 4.7

Tags: ios, actionscript, flash-builder4.5

I have a Action script Mobile Project and I want to export a Release Build. Debug build works perfect, however when I select Export Release Build it hangs at 0 percent even after 24 hours. I have tried restarting, updating JAVA home variable and I don't know what else to do. I might uninstall flash builder and do a fresh install but I wasn't sure if anybody else has seen this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved and the game has been published!

You cannot have an actionscript file with more than 30,000 lines of code....rookie mistake
changing it to 10 files with 3,000 worked like a charm.